# Widgets disappear when main window moved off screen

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, photoimage

I have a tkinter window that I have given a background picture by creating a **Label widget with a PhotoImage instance** (referencing the image instance through Label attributing).

However when I run the script and **move the main window below the start menu** (am using Windows 10) or past the sides of the screens for even one moment, **all the widgets packed onto the Label** (w/ background pic) completely **disappear**.

They only come back (somewhat) upon hovering over them with the mouse it seems. Also the background picture remains and continues to fill the screen. Could it be that the background picture Label is being "lifted" and makes it seem like the widgets are disappearing? If so, how can I prevent this from happening?

The fix that I have found for now is to not use a Label with a PhotoImage as the parent "frame", but instead use a typical Frame widget with only a background color, but this is not ideal.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('600x350+600+300')
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

boxBg = '#666'
frameBg = '#fff'

#problem method
backgroundImg = tk.PhotoImage(file='program_media/background.png')
bgFrame = tk.Label(root, image=backgroundImg)
bgFrame.image = backgroundImg

#less than ideal solution so far
#bgFrame = tk.Frame(root, bg='#fff')

bgFrame.pack(expand=1, fill=tk.BOTH)

mainFrame = tk.Frame(bgFrame)
mainFrame.pack(side=tk.TOP)

title = tk.Label(mainFrame, text='Test String')
title.pack(side=tk.TOP)

#widget creation code packed within mainFrame
#...
#...       All these widgets (including mainFrame above) are disappearing
#...
#end of widget creation code

root.mainloop()
```

See what I mean in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gn46q.png) of BEFORE and AFTER moving the main window below the start menu.

Comment: Just to be clear, you're saying that the _exact_ code that you posted exhibits this problem? It doesn't match your screenshot.

Comment: Looks like you are making a frame after drawing the image.

Comment: Yeah this is just the test code I'm using to figure out the issue, the screenshot is my actual program. The test code is exhibiting the same issue though.